# Testing Rails API with AngularJS and Codepen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, codepen

Having some trouble getting my pen to talk to my dev server on localhost.

I have an angularjs script which is using an $http.get request to get some json from the server, but it results in this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/test' from origin 'https://s.codepen.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

The Rails server and the browser are on the same machine, and I can call the page successfully if I just type the server url direclty into the browser, but I'm not sure how to address this error for scripts running in codepen.

In case of interest the request in my javascript is just:

```
$http.get("localhost:3000/test").then(
   function(response) {
     console.log("success");
   },
   function(response) {
      console.log("failed");
   }
 );
```

Comment: Do you have the `rack-cors` gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: No I do not!  I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uncommenting the `rack-cors` gem in your Gemfile. Then in `config/application.rb` you can configure cors something like this:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Keep in mind, this will allow access from any origin. You'll probably want to change this for your production environment.

Comment: No joy, unfortunately.  I'm not sure the message is actually getting to my rails server though.  It looks as if this is being blocked in the browser somehow before it hits my server. (Note the message referred to above appears in my chrome console, not on the Rails server console.)(